# PhpStorm + PHPUnit failures not displayed in Test Tab

Tags: symfony, testing, phpunit, phpstorm

I want to run tests in my applications in PhpStorm. Application is running on Symfony, for tests I am using PHPUnit and Symfony PHPUnit bridge.

Tests are running, but PhpStorm does not display any failure - it says: "All tests passed". In raw output is log of failure, so test failed (see screenshot), but PhpStorm did not show it.

[image: Screenshot]

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: The failure message is there (it uses TeamCity formatter) .. but it was not detected by IDE for some reason. What is your IDE version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow the issue, Sebastian has changed line endings so we'll have to update our parser.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-42390

https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/commit/56de7e9f96869a808fefc5a2fefbca7970ad2aab

Answer (score 0):

I am using newest version of PHPStorm. I tried to downgrade from PHPUnit 7^ to PHPUnit 6^, after that downgrade it works perfectly. So I found temorary fix for this.